# Create Plane from two Points

Tags: javascript, math, three.js, 3d

So I'm currently developing to create a 3d game using js & three.js.

I'm using **PlaneGeometry** to create walls - what I'd like to implement at this point is some kind of functionality to use two Points to set the translation and rotation of a wall.

So I'd like to have three points `A = ( 0, 0, 0)` and `B = (100, 100, 0)` and `C = (50, 100, 0)` and create a PlaneGeometry with it's matching translation, rotation and size.

```
let geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(?, ?) 
geometry.translate(?, ?, ?) 
geometry.rotateX(?)
geometry.rotateY(?)
geometry.rotateZ(?)
```

---

I'm not sure how I can achieve something like this using Math and Three.js - my aproach was to create the two vectors and calculate the rotation - but this is not really a working solution so after hours of try & error I decided to create this question of SO.

```
let a = new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0)
let b = new THREE.Vector3(100, 100, 0)
let c = new THREE.Vector3(50, 100, 0)

let geometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(a.x - b.x, a.y - b.y)

a.normalize();
b.normalize();
c.normalize();

var quaternion = new THREE.Quaternion();
quaternion.setFromUnitVectors(a, b);

var euler = new THREE.Euler();
euler.setFromQuaternion(quaternion);
geometry.rotateX(euler.toArray()[0])
geometry.rotateX(euler.toArray()[1])
geometry.rotateX(euler.toArray()[2])

var plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: "red", side: THREE.DoubleSide} ) );
scene.add( plane );
```

Comment: Not sure I quite understand: there are an infinite number of planes through two points.You need three points if you want "the" plane.

Comment: Yeah - you're right. For sure I got the three corner points of course.

Comment: Googling for "Threejs plane from three points" yields https://codepen.io/maurizzzio/pen/GjAPYj which looks like what you're trying to do. However, the general theory behind it is very easily found, and can be used to implement what you need in any programming language, so I'd recommend searching for "determine plane through three points" and you should find a _lot_ of great answers.

Comment: [Plane.setFromCoplanarPoints](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Plane.setFromCoplanarPoints) requires three vectors.